# Why do some questions have 40k+ views and thousand of votes?

Tags: support, questions, views

For example this question:

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329243/447356)

Has 40k+ views. Usually a question can have 100-200 views if it's interesting. Why this one is so much viewed?

Comment: You want popular question? Try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13375357/447356)! :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically this happens if the question is featured on another popular web site (Hacker News, Reddit etc) or if it's tweeted by someone like Jeff or Joel. Oh, and appearing on the [podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/) helps, too.

Comment: In this case, it's just that the question is a popular one and comes up in searches often. 40,000+ views are common in [ios] for other frequent questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution), which is half the age of the above-linked question. Something doesn't have to be linked to by an outside site to accumulate a lot of visitors.

Answer (score 8):

When a question gets a lot of views (say more than 2k), it's usually because of one (or more) of the following reasons:

1. It was a "hot" question that made the multicollider.
2. It was linked on another website such as Reddit or Hacker News.
3. It is highly searchable and ranks high on Google searches.

In this example, it looks like the 3rd one applies.